# SharePoint 2013 calculated column not refresh data in ListView

Tags: list-view, calculated-column

Scenario:

I have a list of controller the assets the enterprise. In this list I have a column with the warranty date. A calculated column verifies if the date already expired. When I add or edit an item, everything works great.

Problem:

When someone accesses the list view, information from the calculated field is not updated.
I get no errors, and this works in other lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is with using a calculated field to check against [Today]. The calculation is only run when the item is edited - not when the item is viewed. See http://blog.pentalogic.net/2008/11/truth-about-using-today-in-calculated-columns/

What I would recommend is creating a calendar view for this list and changing your calculated column to something like:

```
=DATE(YEAR([Date last reviewed]),MONTH([Date last reviewed])+[months to expire in],DAY([Date last reviewed]))
```

Comment: I have a similar calculation in another list, it works ...